# Magento 2 with Varnish and Nginx as SSL termination - Endless Redirect

Tags: ssl, nginx, magento2, centos7, varnish

Any Nginx/Varnish/SSL gurus out there? I had my CentOS7 server successfully configured and running Magento 2.17.  Then I decided I wanted to run everything over SSL and have Varnish still cache the pages.

Because Varnish doesn't handle SSL, I reconfigured Varnish and Nginx for SSL termination. Nginx is currently configured to listen on port 443 and to pass the requests to Varnish on port 8081. Varnish is then supposed to serve up the query and return it to Nginx listening on port 8080. When I make a HTTPS request, nginx successfully passes it to Varnish and then, as far as I can tell from the logs, it redirects 20 times before the browser cuts it off and displays the message, "The page isn’t redirecting properly."

It's probably something small and stupid that I haven't been able to spot and a second set of eyes would really be appreciated.

**My nginx test.conf file for the test.com domain:**

```html
## Proxy server to terminate ssl, loop to Varnish-HTTP -> nginx-HTTPS
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name test.com;

    sub_filter 'http://'  'https://';
    sub_filter_once off;

    ## SSL CONFIGURATION
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem;


    # proxy-pass to Varnish
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme https;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_set_header X-Secure on;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name test.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main if=$writelog;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log  error;

    if ($bad_client) { return 444; }

    set $MAGE_ROOT /home/test/public_html;  
    root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;       
        }
 
    ## Process php files (strict rule, define files to be executed)
    location ~ (index|get|static|report|btNenBhQtLNu_opcache_gui|404|503)\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        ## specific security and compatibility headers
        add_header X-Config-By 'Test' always;
        add_header X-Processing-Time $request_time always;
        add_header X-Request-ID $request_id always;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security $hsts_header always;
        add_header X-UA-Compatible 'IE=Edge,chrome=1';
        add_header Link "<$scheme://$http_host$request_uri>; rel=\"canonical\"" always;

        ## php backend settings
        fastcgi_pass        127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index       index.php;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_keep_conn       on;

        # microcache    
        fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
        fastcgi_cache microcache;
        fastcgi_cache_key $scheme|$host|search|$arg_q;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 2h;
        fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
        fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
        fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
        fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
        # microcache
    }

    ## Block other undefined php files, possible injections and random malware hooks.
    location ~* \.php$ { return 404; }      
}
```

**The varnish.params file:**

```html
# Varnish environment configuration description. This was derived from
# the old style sysconfig/defaults settings

# Set this to 1 to make systemd reload try to switch VCL without restart.
RELOAD_VCL=1

# Main configuration file. You probably want to change it.
VARNISH_VCL_CONF=/etc/varnish/default.vcl

# Default address and port to bind to. Blank address means all IPv4
# and IPv6 interfaces, otherwise specify a host name, an IPv4 dotted
# quad, or an IPv6 address in brackets.
VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=8081

# Admin interface listen address and port
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082

# Shared secret file for admin interface
VARNISH_SECRET_FILE=/etc/varnish/secret

# Backend storage specification, see Storage Types in the varnishd(5)
# man page for details.
VARNISH_STORAGE="malloc,1G"

# User and group for the varnishd worker processes
VARNISH_USER=varnish
VARNISH_GROUP=varnish

# Other options, see the man page varnishd(1)
DAEMON_OPTS="-p thread_pool_min=200 \
        -p thread_pool_max=4000 \
        -p thread_pool_add_delay=2 \
        -p cli_timeout=25 \
        -p cli_buffer=26384 \
        -p syslog_cli_traffic=off \
        -p feature=+esi_disable_xml_check,+esi_ignore_other_elements \
        -p vcc_allow_inline_c=on \
        -p timeout_linger=100"
```

**Varnish default.vcl:**

```html
vcl 4.0;
import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 4.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'SSL-OFFLOADED: https'
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
acl purge {
     "localhost";
     "127.0.0.1";
}
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern header required"));
        }
        ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }
    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }
    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }
    # Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
        return (pass);
    }
    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");         
    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);
    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unkown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }          
    }
    # Remove Google gclid parameters to minimize the cache objects
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA&foo=bar"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"&gclid=[^&]+",""); # strips when QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA" or QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA&bar=baz"
    # static files are always cacheable. remove SSL flag and cookie
        if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/.*\.(ico|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|tiff|bmp|mp3|ogg|svg|swf|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$") {
        unset req.http.Https;    
        unset req.http.SSL-OFFLOADED;                 
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    }
    return (hash);
}        
sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }
    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
    if (req.http.host) {      
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);     
    }
    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning   
    if (req.http.SSL-OFFLOADED) {
        hash_data(req.http.SSL-OFFLOADED);
    }

}
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {            
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }                 
    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }
    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;     
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {               
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }
    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    # images, css and js are cacheable by default so we have to remove cookie also
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        if (bereq.url !~ "\.(ico|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|tiff|bmp|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|svg|swf|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)(\?|$)") {
            set beresp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
            set beresp.http.Expires = "-1";
            set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
            set beresp.grace = 1m;
        }
    }
   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
        beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
        (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control && beresp.http.Vary == "*")) {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;                
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }
    return (deliver);
}
sub vcl_deliver {                
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;                     
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;          
    unset resp.http.Link;
}
```

**Report of ports by netstat:**

```html
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1027/php-fpm: maste 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      733/hhvm            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2721/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13657/redis-server  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5131            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1412/proftpd: (acce 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      997/memcached       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6380          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1028/redis-server 1 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9142/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9142/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9760/varnishd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2308/lookup-domain- 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7224            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      984/sshd            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9142/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9760/varnishd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17668           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2861/perl           
tcp6       0      0 :::7224                 :::*                    LISTEN      984/sshd
```

Varnish Log of the redirect requests (there are 20; these are 2):

```html
*   << Request  >> 294986    
-   Begin          req 294985 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1496891464.408694 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1496891464.408694 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 4702
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 69.227.13.164
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Host: test.com
-   ReqHeader      Host: test.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Scheme: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Real-IP: 69.227.13.164
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   ReqHeader      X-Secure: on
-   ReqHeader      Connection: close
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: PHPSESSID=344hlkmot8oi8ooop0ugnprc47
-   ReqHeader      DNT: 1
-   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 69.227.13.164
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 69.227.13.164, 127.0.0.1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqURL         /
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 294987 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1496891464.447563 0.038869 0.038869
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     302
-   RespReason     Found
-   RespHeader     Server: nginx
-   RespHeader     Date: Thu, 08 Jun 2017 03:11:04 GMT
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   RespHeader     Location: https://test.com/
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
-   RespHeader     Expires: Wed, 08 Jun 2016 03:11:04 GMT
-   RespHeader     X-Magento-Debug: 1
-   RespHeader     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   RespHeader     X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   RespHeader     X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   RespHeader     X-Config-By: Honey
-   RespHeader     X-Processing-Time: 0.039
-   RespHeader     X-Request-ID: ce5053ee7177817d0d8f612aff673a32
-   RespHeader     X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
-   RespHeader     Link: <http://test.com/>; rel="canonical"
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 294986
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespHeader     X-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS
-   RespUnset      X-Magento-Debug: 1
-   RespUnset      Server: nginx
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 294986
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
-   RespUnset      Link: <http://test.com/>; rel="canonical"
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1496891464.447622 0.038928 0.000059
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 20
-   Debug          "RES_MODE 2"
-   RespHeader     Connection: close
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1496891464.447669 0.038975 0.000047
-   ReqAcct        540 0 540 600 20 620
-   End            

*   << Session  >> 294985    
-   Begin          sess 0 HTTP/1
-   SessOpen       127.0.0.1 4702 127.0.0.1:8081 127.0.0.1 8081 1496891464.408655 19
-   Link           req 294986 rxreq
-   SessClose      RESP_CLOSE 0.039
-   End
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a redirect being issued to `https://` because your back-end doesn't know it's being served on HTTPS (and presumably you configured it as being, so it generates https links etc). You need to convince Magento it's on HTTPS even when it looks like it's not. In a similar setup with Apache I use:

```
<If "-R '192.0.0.1'">
     SetEnvIfNoCase X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
</If>
```

Not sure what the syntax is for NGINX, but hopefully this should set you on the right track.